# Resolve colliding rotated rectangles by moving along vector

Tags: javascript, math, collision

I have a javascript program that places rectangles one at a time along walls in a room in **counter-clockwise** order. I use the coordinates of the rectangles corners for collision detection. It skips the placement of a rectangle if it intersects with another rectangle in the room.

[image: Currently, it simply skips this rectangle]

(the room can be any shape so collisions can happen on any side of the rectangle)

[image]

However, I want to move the rectangle along the wall until it is no longer colliding instead of skipping it. My current idea is to move the rectangle 1 coordinate at a time in a loop until it no longer intersects, but it does not seem like a good solution for performance.

[image: I want to move the rectangle out of the collision to the counter-clockwise direction]

Is there a way to mathematically know how far in a given direction the rotated rectangle needs to be moved in order to no longer intersect another rotated rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using of Separating Axis Theorem.

Two boxes (polygons in wide sense) don't intersect, if there exists some axis parallel to some box side, separating boxes, so the lie at distinct sides of this axis.

[image]

I've got [arbitrary paper with good picture](https://www.jkh.me/files/tutorials/Separating%20Axis%20Theorem%20for%20Oriented%20Bounding%20Boxes.pdf). At pages 16-17 we can see two boxes and some formulas to check for intersection.

You can express `T` - difference vector between box center as

```
T.x = pb.x - pa.x + t * dx
T.y = pb.y - pa.y + t * dy
```

where `t` is parameter (0 in the starting moment), and `(dx, dy)` is direction vector for B box moving (along the slanted wall at your picture).

Substituting `T` components into formula (note I changed `>` sign to `=`) we can get equation for parameter `t` corresponding to moment when Ax becomes separating axis.

```
| T • Ax | = WA + | ( WB*Bx ) • Ax  | + |( HB*By ) • Ax |
```

If we make the same for other axes (Ay, Bx, By), we get 4 values of `t`, and the **smallest positive** one corresponds to minimal diplacement needed to separate the boxes.

Note that right part contains only constant values (for given setup), and we can easily calculate it using `abs` function, but left part contains variable, so we have to consider two cases (negative and positive dot product `T • Ax`) to find solution(s). Two possible solutions correspond to "left and right" box separation (anyway, you need smaller positive result)